# Core JS Typeahead Bloodhound - results available read to screen reader

Tags: javascript, accessibility, typeahead.js, bloodhound, nvda

Wondering if anyone has this experience with typeahead.js and bloodhound (from [this repo](https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js)). When I get bloodhound suggestions from an AJAX request, the total number of results available are read to the screen reader (NVDA). When I get them from just a local JSON or JS object, they aren't read to the screen reader. The suggestions show up to a sighted user just fine, but the screen reader says "0 results are available".

I can't get NVDA to read either case in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmdolbow/uaefh0dx/18/) but all the code is there. To complement the fiddle, I created [a Github repo](https://mmdolbow.github.io/typeaheadmvp/), where the error can be reproduced. Sorry it's probably way more code than is needed to troubleshoot the situation. Below is the snippet of the Bloodhound setup for the static data.

```js
//Bloodhound for other / alt / fake data
var otherBH = new Bloodhound({
  name: "other",
  datumTokenizer: function (o) {
    var addr= Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(o.addr);
    return addr;
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  identify: function(other) {return other.addr; },
  local: function() {
    var list = [];
    $.each(altdata,function(rec,val){
      list.push({addr: val.fakeaddr, source: "other"});
    });
    return list;
  }
})
otherBH.initialize();
```

Comment: I want to become more active in the accessibility section.  I'm great at testing out jsfiddles, but I know nothing about screen readers or NVDA.  Can you please tell me what I need to know to test this jsfiddle out in a way that will help you and others.  Are you asking for help from desktop machines?  Windows or Mac?  Does it matter?  I will delete this comment soon if I don't get an answer from someone.

Comment: Also, I think you might be aware, but your stack snippet has this error: "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: Bloodhound is not defined",

Comment: I'm using NVDA on Windows 10. It's a free desktop app and serves as a screen reader for folks who are blind or low-vision. It will read out pretty much anything you point it to. Since I can't get it to read the fiddle, though, I'm considering pushing this code into a Github repo.

Comment: OK, latest edit is for some trimmed code and pointing to my Github repo that demonstrates this issue. Any help is much appreciated.